# Will these delete my files? (fixpart)

Tags: partitioning

I'm applying a fixpart command so Ubuntu amd64 install will detect windows installation and install alongside it.

i applied this command, i haven't chose yet, if i chose Y will it delete everything on my disk?

```
sudo fixparts /dev/sda
FixParts 0.8.4
Loading MBR data from /dev/sda

NOTICE: GPT signatures detected on the disk, but no 0xEE protective partition! The GPT signatures are probably left over from a previous partition table.

Do you want to delete them (if you answer 'Y', this will happen immediately)? (Y/N):
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what happened? Does it deleted your files?

Answer (score 1):

It could. Normally it would not, but it found an error. I would backup your data before you try. If your using your GUID partition table then you will have data loss. If it is a left over and not in use then your fine. Again I would highly recommend backing up first, but it *should* be fine.